# How to get child of nested divs without ids

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to set a width using jQuery on the following div. 
My HTML looks like this (some of it is generated by a lightbox plugin):

```
<div class="xxxgallery"> (this is unique and gives me a point to select the children from)
    <h2></h2>
    <div class="cat slick-initialized slick-slider slick-dotted" role="toolbar">
          <div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list draggable">
               <div class="slick-track">
                     //more code
               </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the div I need is the one with the class=slick-track.
Note that I cannot work directly using $('.slick-track'), because I have 8 of these galleries on my page, and only the top div class="xxxgallery" is unique, the rest is the same for all the other 7 galleries, but the width that I need to set using jQuery is different for all those 7.

Comment: is the structure same? they all will have same no of nested divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said the first div (class="xxxgallery") was unique, using either CSS or jQuery your selector would be:

```
div.xxxgallery div.slick-track
```

You could get more specific if you needed to with:

```
div.xxxgallery > div.cat.slick-initialized.slick-slider.slick-dotted > div.slick-list.draggable > div.slick-track
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but *«...but the width that I need to set using jQuery ...»* was quite clear. I suppose this is why.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette It doesn't matter, the selector is the same in this case for both CSS and jQuery. In jQuery it would just be wrapped in `$()` like `$('div.xxxgallery div.slick-track')`. In CSS, it would just be `div.xxxgallery div.slick-track {}`. I guess whatever coward downvoted was also clueless in both jQuery and CSS

Comment: @j08691 I'm also an advocate for CSS over JQuery, not sure why this solution merits a downvote.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(".xxxgallery").find(".slick-track")
```

Comment: why not just $('.xxxgallery .slick-track') ?